# google angular module don't work

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, module, angularjs-module

I add this to my proyect: https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/

i follow the suggestion and add this files to my proyect mvc in the BundleConfig (Downloaded by Nuget):

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/map").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/lodash.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/angular-google-maps-street-view.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/angular-google-maps.min.js"));
```

in the app.js have this:

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'uiGmapgoogle-maps']).config(configRoute);

    configRoute.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];

    function configRoute($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'scripts/app/partials/Home.html',
                controller: 'productosPrincipalCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .when('/mapa', {
                templateUrl: 'scripts/app/partials/mapa.html'
            })
            .when('/ofertas/:type', {
                templateUrl: 'scripts/app/partials/productos.html',
                controller: 'listProductsCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .when('/oferta-detalle/:type', {
                templateUrl: 'scripts/app/partials/producto-detalle.html',
                controller: 'productDetailCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            })
            .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    }

})();
```

in the layout i load the scripts:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Ofertas al Toque</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")*@
    <script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#/home" class="navbar-brand">MyPagina</a>
                 .
                 .
                 .
                 .
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/map")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

and when run the app this throw a error and nothing load in the page, if i errase the 'uiGmapgoogle-maps' all works good, but i need the maps.

Note: I dont use map in the main page but i have the error too

the error throw angular is this: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.8%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DuiGmapgoogle-maps

if somebody can help me please.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use full development version for more verbose error messages and stack trace output. Sounds like you aren't loading the maps module properly. Check network tab in developer tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed add this scripts for don't throw more the error:

https://github.com/nmccready/angular-simple-logger

Note: Nuget don't download this automatically.